# Avoid duplicate product while using variations

Tags: commerce

I am new to drupal and fetching Drupal commerce variations from Views and the products are getting duplicated what would be the best way to avoid duplicate when using product variations. Here are the screenshots from views
http://puu.sh/vn1Po/75e158f5c5.png
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you reference multiple products per display node, so adding that relationship results in multiple rows. A real easy solution is to filter by the delta value from your product reference field so that only the first referenced product results in a row being shown. Ideally we'd add another filter that let you filter by the *default* delta value, as that can differ from 0 if altered via code.

The filter you're looking for should read something like: **Content: Product (field_product:delta)** and you should set the filter value to 0. No need to expose it.

Answer (score 0):

You may get it to work using the [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module. From its project page:

> Relationships or other joins in Views often create "duplicate" results. For example, a node with a field that has multiple values may show up in the View once per value in the multi-value field. It's frustrating, and the "DISTINCT" SQL query option in the Views UI does not actually solve the problem because the result row is technically distinct. This module aims to give a simple GUI method to remove or aggregate these "duplicate" rows.